# How to append the hex color code

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

Im using jquery-ui to make a color picker and im almost done with it.
But i was wondering how i could append the hex color code.

HTML

```
 <div id="slider-horizontal"></div>
 <div class="pin"></div>
```

JQUERY

```
$(function() {
    var box = $('.pin')[0];

    $("#slider-horizontal").slider({
        orientation: "horizontal",
        min: 0,
        max: 360,
        value: 0,
        slide: function(event, ui) {
            box.style.background = 'hsl(' + ui.value + ', 100%, 50%)';
        }
    });
});
```

Any guidance would be appreciated. Thanks very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[This](https://github.com/mjackson/mjijackson.github.com/blob/master/2008/02/rgb-to-hsl-and-rgb-to-hsv-color-model-conversion-algorithms-in-javascript.txt) page has many functions for converting from HSL to RGB. Using this function, you could have a div that has the RGB value in it, updated with the slide event along with the background color. Here is a snippet of the function:

```
/**
 * Converts an HSL color value to RGB. Conversion formula
 * adapted from http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HSL_color_space.
 * Assumes h, s, and l are contained in the set [0, 1] and
 * returns r, g, and b in the set [0, 255].
 *
 * @param   Number  h       The hue
 * @param   Number  s       The saturation
 * @param   Number  l       The lightness
 * @return  Array           The RGB representation
 */
function hslToRgb(h, s, l){
    var r, g, b;

    if(s == 0){
        r = g = b = l; // achromatic
    }else{
        function hue2rgb(p, q, t){
            if(t < 0) t += 1;
            if(t > 1) t -= 1;
            if(t < 1/6) return p + (q - p) * 6 * t;
            if(t < 1/2) return q;
            if(t < 2/3) return p + (q - p) * (2/3 - t) * 6;
            return p;
        }

        var q = l < 0.5 ? l * (1 + s) : l + s - l * s;
        var p = 2 * l - q;
        r = hue2rgb(p, q, h + 1/3);
        g = hue2rgb(p, q, h);
        b = hue2rgb(p, q, h - 1/3);
    }

    return [r * 255, g * 255, b * 255];
}
```

Going from RGB to HEX is much simpler, and can be achieved with the following functions from [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5623838/rgb-to-hex-and-hex-to-rgb):

```
function componentToHex(c) {
var hex = c.toString(16);
return hex.length == 1 ? "0" + hex : hex;
}

function rgbToHex(r, g, b) {
    return "#" + componentToHex(r) + componentToHex(g) + componentToHex(b);
}
```